# Select data using if statement to show Not Available for missing values

Tags: mysql, select

I have a database table in `mysql` that store types like "temperature" , "oxygen_saturation" , "heart_rate" , "systolic_pressure" , "diastolic_pressure".

However, for a given checkup_id, some types may not stored. Those I want to show them as N/A.

My table is the following:

```
CREATE TABLE `exam` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `checkup_id` int NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `result` longtext NOT NULL,
  `combined_exam_id` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',
  `status` tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `version_id` int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`version_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `exam_id` (`id`,`version_id`) /*!80000 INVISIBLE */,
  KEY `checkup_idx` (`checkup_id`) /*!80000 INVISIBLE */,
  KEY `version_id_fk_exam_idx` (`version_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `exam_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`checkup_id`) REFERENCES `endorse_checkup` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `version_id_fk_exam` FOREIGN KEY (`version_id`) REFERENCES `ps_versioning` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=65 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I have the following select statement:

```
SELECT end_up.id as checkup_id,
    end_e.type, 
    end_e.result,
FROM  endorse_exam as end_e
left JOIN endorse_checkup as end_up on end_up.id = end_e.checkup_id
left JOIN ps_versioning  as v ON v.id = end_e.version_id
left JOIN u_users  as u ON u.user_id = v.user_id
WHERE end_up.patient_id = 50 AND v.id <= (SELECT IF(164 > -1, 164, max(v.id))) and checkup_id = 25;
```

Note: I put 164 value by hand, but actually it comes through an API.

Using the SQL code above, I get a result like

[image]

However, I want to create a query to get info like:

[image]

Comment: `IF(164 > -1, 164, max(v.id))` I would guess that as 164 is ALWAYS > -1 that test is a bit of a odd ball and may not be what you intended

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes, that's not an issue. It's because part of a stored-procedure.

Comment: You cannot show what is not there, because you dont know what all the possibilities of what might be there are. Unless you create another table with all the possible types in  and us  that i the query also

Comment: @RiggsFolly in Southern Hemisphere, `164 < -1` because they live upside-down. I hope it makes sense

Comment: @Cid Thank you, that got the chuckle muscle working